# What's the default username and password for the RCA L10T BT media player?

Tags: passwords, login, media-player

I have an RCA L10T BT media player device.
I lost the manual and can't seem to find a download,
so I don't know what the default username and password is to connect
to its web interface. Does anybody know it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By accident I guessed it

username: admin
password: 123

Hope it helps others

Comment: Better put that in a password manager now ;-)

Comment: Better change it and put it in a password manager ;)